# Passing a serialize form and array in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a form which contains a bool and DataTable which I have converted to an array as per the Datatable documentation.

```
var aData = $('#dtPurchaseEnquiryLines').DataTable().rows().data().toArray();
var formData = $("#PurchaseEnquiryDetails").serializeArray();   
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/PurchaseEnquiry/UpdatePEHeader",
    data: { oPE: jsonData, oLines: aData } 
 })
```

If I pass it using serializeArray the bool from the form is always passing back as false.

If i set the set as

```
var formData = $("#PurchaseEnquiryDetails").serialize();
```

The form is passing to the controller as null. If i remove the datatable array input from the ajax the from passes to the controller fine with the bool as true.

I have tried building an object for both inputs and posting this as stringify but then the datatable array is null on the controller albeit the form has passed correctly.

I do have a working solution which is

```
var aData = $('#dtPurchaseEnquiryLines').DataTable().rows().dat();

var formData = $("#PurchaseEnquiryDetails").serialize();


var jsonData = {};
       

$(formData).each(function (index, obj) {
          if (obj.name === "ReviewRequired1" && !jsonData.hasOwnProperty(obj.name)) {
        jsonData[obj.name] = obj.value; } 
else if (!jsonData.hasOwnProperty(obj.name)) {
  jsonData[obj.name] = obj.value; }
 });

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/PurchaseEnquiry/UpdatePEHeader",
     data: { oPE: jsonData, oLines: aData } 
})
```

I just think that seems a bit of a messy solution. Could someone help?